# Appcelerator studio can't update stuck at "checking for new Appcelerator Updates..."

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I'm using appcelerator studio version 4.5.0 updated in 2016.4.30

But I can't update it recently, it will stuck at "checking for new Appcelerator Updates..." and I must close it and reopen it to use continuely.

Hope someone could help me how to solve it...

Comment: Can you check studio log: Help > Studio > View Log File, do you see any error here?

Comment: There were some timeout errors.
[ERROR] com.appcelerator.titanium.update.core/debug/sdk_update Error getting release lists from url 'https://f4df0833a1352ef193633d85356e6e80ffcdcdb7.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com/api/mobilesdk/releases/3a8e2aec-e56c-4512-9f1f-bac9e54f6b74'

Comment: Can you upload entire log here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8535. If you have reproducible steps please update in the ticket.